# Trying to build Assimp as a submodule in Cmake it can't find zlib

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-modules

I am building zlib & assimp as submodules for my project.  Assimp fails to build after Zlib successfully compiles saying it can't find zlib.h

This is how I'm building my current submodule directory. Zlib.h seems to be a built as part of the zlib build. So I'm not sure how to get the other projects to recognize where the zlib header is.

```
add_subdirectory(zlib)
add_subdirectory(glad)
add_subdirectory(sdl2)
add_subdirectory(spdlog)
add_subdirectory(yamlcpp)
add_subdirectory(assimp)
add_subdirectory(nlohmann_json ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nlohmann_json)

#Find system packages to link
find_package(OpenGL COMPONENTS OpenGL REQUIRED)

set(GLM_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glm)
add_library(glm INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(glm INTERFACE ${GLM_PATH})

set(ENTT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/entt/single_include)
add_library(EnTT INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(EnTT INTERFACE ${ENTT_PATH})

set(IMGUI_PROJECT_NAME ImGui)
set(IMGUI_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/imgui)
file(GLOB IMGUI_SOURCES ${IMGUI_PATH}/*.cpp ${IMGUI_PATH}/backends/imgui_impl_sdl.cpp ${IMGUI_PATH}/backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp)
add_library(${IMGUI_PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${IMGUI_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${IMGUI_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${IMGUI_PATH})
target_link_libraries(${IMGUI_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE OpenGL::GL SDL2 glad)
```

edit: CMake output
Configuring folder:

```
KEngine 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -Hc:/Dev/KEngine -Bc:/Dev/KEngine/build -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T host=x64 -A x64
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
[cmake] CMake Deprecation Warning at modules/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
[cmake]   Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
[cmake]   CMake.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
[cmake]   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
[cmake]     Reason given by package: The command
[cmake]       "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pkg-config.exe" --version
[cmake]     failed with output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     stderr: 
[cmake]       
[cmake]     result: 
[cmake] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- SDL2 was configured with the following options:
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- Platform: Windows-10.0.19043
[cmake] -- 64-bit:   TRUE
[cmake] -- Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
[cmake] -- Revision: https://github.com/DeveloperChaseLewis/KEngine.git@63f74969dc82247490ac24bf4994c60e35370330
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- Subsystems:
[cmake] --   Atomic:    ON
[cmake] --   Audio: ON
[cmake] --   Video: ON
[cmake] --   Render:    ON
[cmake] --   Events:    ON
[cmake] --   Joystick:  ON
[cmake] --   Haptic:    ON
[cmake] --   Power: ON
[cmake] --   Threads:   ON
[cmake] --   Timers:    ON
[cmake] --   File:  ON
[cmake] --   Loadso:    ON
[cmake] --   CPUinfo:   ON
[cmake] --   Filesystem:    ON
[cmake] --   Dlopen:    ON
[cmake] --   Sensor:    ON
[cmake] --   Locale:    ON
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- Options:
[cmake] --   SDL_3DNOW                   (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ALSA                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ALSA_SHARED             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ALTIVEC                 (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ARMNEON                 (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ARMSIMD                 (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ARTS                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ARTS_SHARED             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ASAN                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ASSEMBLY                (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ASSERTIONS              (Wanted: auto): auto
[cmake] --   SDL_BACKGROUNDING_SIGNAL    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_CLOCK_GETTIME           (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_COCOA                   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_DIRECTFB                (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_DIRECTFB_SHARED         (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_DIRECTX                 (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_DISKAUDIO               (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_DUMMYAUDIO              (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_DUMMYVIDEO              (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ESD                     (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_ESD_SHARED              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_FOREGROUNDING_SIGNAL    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_FUSIONSOUND             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_FUSIONSOUND_SHARED      (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_GCC_ATOMICS             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_HIDAPI                  (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_JACK                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_JACK_SHARED             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_KMSDRM                  (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_KMSDRM_SHARED           (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_LIBC                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_LIBSAMPLERATE           (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_LIBSAMPLERATE_SHARED    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_METAL                   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_MMX                     (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_NAS                     (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_NAS_SHARED              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_OFFSCREEN               (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_OPENGL                  (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_OPENGLES                (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_OSS                     (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_PIPEWIRE                (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_PIPEWIRE_SHARED         (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_PTHREADS                (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_PTHREADS_SEM            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_PULSEAUDIO              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_PULSEAUDIO_SHARED       (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_RENDER_D3D              (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_RENDER_METAL            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_RPATH                   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_RPI                     (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_SNDIO                   (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_SNDIO_SHARED            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_SSE                     (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_SSE2                    (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_SSE3                    (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_SSEMATH                 (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_STATIC_PIC              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_TEST                    (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_VIRTUAL_JOYSTICK        (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_VIVANTE                 (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_VULKAN                  (Wanted: ON): ON
[cmake] --   SDL_WASAPI                  (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_WAYLAND                 (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_WAYLAND_LIBDECOR        (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_WAYLAND_LIBDECOR_SHARED (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_WAYLAND_QT_TOUCH        (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_WAYLAND_SHARED          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11                     (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_SHARED              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_XCURSOR             (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_XINERAMA            (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_XINPUT              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_XRANDR              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_XSCRNSAVER          (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_XSHAPE              (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_X11_XVM                 (Wanted: OFF): OFF
[cmake] --   SDL_XINPUT                  (Wanted: ON): OFF
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] --  CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od 
[cmake] --  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG: /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] --  CFLAGS:        /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  "-IC:/Dev/KEngine/modules/sdl2/src/hidapi/hidapi"
[cmake] --  EXTRA_CFLAGS:  
[cmake] --  EXTRA_LDFLAGS: 
[cmake] --  EXTRA_LIBS:    user32;gdi32;winmm;imm32;ole32;oleaut32;version;uuid;advapi32;setupapi;shell32;dinput8
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] --  Build Shared Library: ON
[cmake] --  Build Static Library: ON
[cmake] --  Build Static Library with Position Independent Code: OFF
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- Build spdlog: 1.9.2
[cmake] -- Build type: Debug
[cmake] -- Shared libraries enabled
[cmake] -- Looking for ZLIB...
[cmake] -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
[cmake]     Reason given by package: The command
[cmake]       "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pkg-config.exe" --version
[cmake]     failed with output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     stderr: 
[cmake]       
[cmake]     result: 
[cmake] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
[cmake] -- Enabled importer formats: AMF 3DS AC ASE ASSBIN B3D BVH COLLADA DXF CSM HMP IRRMESH IRR LWO LWS M3D MD2 MD3 MD5 MDC MDL NFF NDO OFF OBJ OGRE OPENGEX PLY MS3D COB BLEND IFC XGL FBX Q3D Q3BSP RAW SIB SMD STL TERRAGEN 3D X X3D GLTF 3MF MMD
[cmake] -- Disabled importer formats:
[cmake] -- Enabled exporter formats: OBJ OPENGEX PLY 3DS ASSBIN ASSXML M3D COLLADA FBX STL X X3D GLTF 3MF PBRT ASSJSON STEP
[cmake] -- Disabled exporter formats:
[cmake] -- Using the single-header code from C:/Dev/KEngine/modules/nlohmann_json/single_include/
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Dev/KEngine/build
[main] Building folder: KEngine SANDBOX
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build c:/Dev/KEngine/build --config Debug --target SANDBOX -j 18 --
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build]   Checking File Globs
[build]   spdlog.vcxproj -> C:\Dev\KEngine\build\bin\spdlogd.dll
[build]   zlib.vcxproj -> C:\Dev\KEngine\build\bin\zlibd1.dll
[build]   yaml-cpp.vcxproj -> C:\Dev\KEngine\build\lib\yaml-cppd.lib
[build]   glad.vcxproj -> C:\Dev\KEngine\build\bin\gladd.dll
[build]   SDL2.vcxproj -> C:\Dev\KEngine\build\bin\SDL2d.dll
[build]   ImGui.vcxproj -> C:\Dev\KEngine\build\lib\ImGuid.lib
[build]   ZipArchiveIOSystem.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\contrib\unzip\unzip.h(25,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   AssbinLoader.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\Assbin\AssbinLoader.cpp(61,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   BlenderLoader.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\Blender\BlenderLoader.cpp(70,14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   IFCLoader.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\contrib\unzip\unzip.h(25,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   XGLLoader.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\XGL\XGLLoader.cpp(63,14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   FBXParser.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\FBX\FBXParser.cpp(50,13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   Q3BSPFileImporter.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\Q3BSP\Q3BSPFileImporter.cpp(52,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   XFileParser.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\X\XFileParser.cpp(64,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   AssbinFileWriter.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\Assbin\AssbinFileWriter.cpp(54,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   AssxmlFileWriter.cpp
[build] C:\Dev\KEngine\modules\assimp\code\AssetLib\Assxml\AssxmlFileWriter.cpp(59,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\KEngine\build\modules\assimp\code\assimp.vcxproj]
[build]   Generating Code...
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
[main] Failed to prepare executable target with name 'undefined'
```

Comment: "Assimp fails to build after Zlib successfully compiles saying it can't find zlib.h" - Please, provide the **exact** error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev added the output, i'm on windows currently. After I get the project a bit farther I'm wanting to get it to cross compile on Linux.